# I have multiple submit buttons and a validation issue with the second form

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have two forms that are hidden when submitted. The validation for the second form isn't working. Any clue as to why?

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $feet = $_POST['feet'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];   
        if(!is_numeric($feet)){
            $isValid = false;
            $feetError = "Try again buddy"; 
        }
        echo "Hello Captain " . $lname . " Are you" . $feet ."ft tall?";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        $feet2 = $_POST['feet2'];
        $lname2 = $_POST['lname2'];
        $isValid2 = true;
        if(!is_numeric($feet2)){
            $isValid2 = false;
            $feetError2 = "Try again buddy";    
        }
        echo "Hello Captain " . $lname2 . " Are you" . $feet2 ."ft tall?";
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <form name="formie" id="formie" action="test1.php" method="post">
    <p><label>square feet</label><input type="text" id="feet" name="feet"><span><?PHP echo $feetError; ?></span></p>
    <p><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"></p>
    <p><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>

     <form name="formie2" id="formie2" action="test1.php" method="post">

    <p><label>square feet</label><input type="text" id="feet2" name="feet2"><span><?PHP echo $feetError2; ?></span></p>
    <p><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lname2" name="lname2"></p>
    <p><button type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2">Submit</button></p>
</form>
<?PHP
    }
    ?>
```

These are all place holders BTW. The project I'm working on is much much larger, I just want to understand the whole 'hiding forms' thing before I try to implement it on a larger scale.
Thank You guys!

Comment: Because only one form is submitted per button click. Unless you're using JavaScript you cannot submit more than one form at a time.

Comment: What does _"isn't working"_ mean? Any errors? Btw, you're never display your error messages. Your code will just keep going and printing out the "Hello Captain"-results, even if the validation fails.

Comment: By doesn't work what I mean is that if I put in a bunch of letters into the first input on the second form, instead of getting "Try again buddy" I get the letters to show up. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, and if you read my previous comment you see why you still get that message. You're _always_ printing the "Hello Captain"-message, regardless if the validation failed or not. And the error is never shown, since that get's printed in the `else` block, which isn't shown at all at this time. Btw, when the form is shown, you should get a couple of _"Undefined variable $feetError"_ and _"$feetError2"_, since those aren't defined in that `else`-block.

Answer (score 1):

```
$isSubmitted = false;
$isValid = true;
$isValid2 = true;
$feetError = '';
$feetError2 = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $isSubmitted = true;
    $feet = $_POST['feet'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];   
    if(!is_numeric($feet)){
        $isValid = false;
        $feetError = "Try again buddy"; 
    } else {
        echo "Hello Captain " . $lname . " Are you" . $feet ."ft tall?";
    }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $isSubmitted = true;
    $feet2 = $_POST['feet2'];
    $lname2 = $_POST['lname2'];
    if(!is_numeric($feet2)){
        $isValid2 = false;
        $feetError2 = "Try again buddy";    
    } else {
        echo "Hello Captain " . $lname2 . " Are you" . $feet2 ."ft tall?";
    }
}
?>

<?php if(!$isSubmitted || !$isValid || !$isValid2) { ?>

<form name="formie" id="formie" action="test1.php" method="post">
<p><label>square feet</label><input type="text" id="feet" name="feet"><span><?PHP echo $feetError; ?></span></p>
<p><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"></p>
<p><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>

 <form name="formie2" id="formie2" action="test1.php" method="post">

<p><label>square feet</label><input type="text" id="feet2" name="feet2"><span><?PHP echo $feetError2; ?></span></p>
<p><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lname2" name="lname2"></p>
<p><button type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2">Submit</button></p>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

When you submit a form, the PHP reloads the page. When the page is reloaded, it is reloaded WITH the previous posted values of your form. Therefore it will always trigger your first condition assuming the user is submitting the first form first.

You have 2 solutions. Do separate script, or use another if, instead the if - else. I'd recommend separate script though.

I recommend separate script for each form, with a header redirecting to your website after, it's easier to remember and to order your work afterwards.

Comment: It won't reload the page with the previous values. It will post the values from the form that was submitted. If the second form is submitted, If the second form is submitted, it shouldn't trigger the first condition (since the names of the submit-buttons are different).

Comment: You're absolutely right, i assumed the user did post the first form, but it does "reload" the page though. I editted to be more accurate.

Comment: Sure, but your answer doesn't really address the OP's actual issue. You're just suggesting an alternative way of structuring the code. The way the OP has done it should still work. And until we get an explanation of what the OP means by _"doesn't work"_, we're just guessing.

Comment: Anyway if it's just placeholders, there might be a simple mistake in the HTML too as far as we know. But i really think it's about this elif... 
Simply replace it by a IF should do the trick.

Comment: @Magnus 
By doesn't work what I mean is that if I put in a bunch of letters into the first input on the second form, instead of getting "Try again buddy" I get the letters to show up. Hope that helps.

Oh and I'm not getting errors either. So my logic is flawed? I dunno.

Comment: @theBartender Acutally, yes, your logic is flawed. The validation is done correctly. But your "echo Hello Captain ..." is OUTSIDE the validation. Which means it will display the message even in case of bad informations. You should add an else{} condition after your validation, to display your message. And display some kind of error or tips for the user in case of bad informations.

Comment: @NoxWorld, Thanks, that did it!